# OpenSCAD parser error when there is no visible error with the code

Tags: openscad

Code:

```
magnet_radius = 17.45/2; //for a 17.45mm diameter magnet
magnet_thickness = 3.90/2; //for a 3.90mm thick magnet

main_module();

module main_module(){
    top_surface();
}

module top_surface(){
    difference(){
        cylinder(h=0.40, r1=magnet_radius*5, r2=magnet_radius*5);
        cutaway();
}

module cutaway(){
    cylinder(h=0.40, r1=magnet_radius*1.05, r2=magnet_radius*1.05);
}
```

It was working just a second ago. Now it's not working anymore. Please help.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing curly brace for "difference(){"

Comment: Thanks. I wish OpenSCAD had autofill features where these trivial things are taken care of. It doesn't even have automatic indentation correction feature.

Is there a better IDE I can use while using the same OpenSCAD language?

Comment: @user1478983 You can use any editor you like to edit the files externally. Under the `Design` menu check `Automatic Reload and Preview`. When you save the `.scad` file in your external editor, the preview will be updated.